# Best way to order a List<type> by field C# Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have the following code that works fine, but I was wondering if there is any better way to order the select depending on what the user choose.

```
public List<TB_PRODUTO> GetAll(int ID_Empresa, String Order)
{
    if(Order.Equals("COD_HERBALIFE"))
        return Ent.TB_PRODUTO.Where(x => x.ID_EMPRESA == ID_Empresa).Select(x => x).OrderBy(x => x.COD_HERBALIFE).ToList();
    else if (Order.Equals("DESCRICAO"))
        return Ent.TB_PRODUTO.Where(x => x.ID_EMPRESA == ID_Empresa).Select(x => x).OrderBy(x => x.DESCRICAO).ToList();
    else
       return Ent.TB_PRODUTO.Where(x => x.ID_EMPRESA == ID_Empresa).Select(x => x).OrderBy(x => x.PRECO).ToList();        
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: aside note: `Select(x => x)` is just _pointless_

Comment: Have you tried dynamic Query  (LINQ) library? here is the [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
private static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, null);
}

public List<TB_PRODUTO> GetAll(int ID_Empresa, String Order)
{
    return Ent.TB_PRODUTO.Where(x => x.ID_EMPRESA == ID_Empresa).Select(x => x).OrderBy(x => GetPropertyValue(x, Order)).ToList();
}
```

GetPropertyValue will return the property matching the Order string, provided the string exactly matches the property.